# Does call by value of a function change the original value of the parameters?

Tags: c++

Would this function change the original values in the matrix that I use to call this function?
Thank you for the help.

```
void powerup(char mat[9][9])
 {
  for(int i=0;i<9;++i)
   {
    for(int j=0;j<9;++j)
     {
      mat[i][j]=su[i][j];
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be call by value, though.

Comment: You call is a call via pointer (and changes the value)

Comment: I downvoted you, because your question does not show research effort. It is a good question as it is not trivial what happens with the non trivial parameter (is anything in C++ trivial? xD), but not how it is now. Consider adding information too it.

Comment: Hey guys.Sorry @Micha90 if it was a stupid question. I'm just a beginner,so what I learned was that when you want to call by reference you have to add an '&' symbol before the parameter when you define it. Cleared the misconception for in the case of arrays anyway.Thanks and maybe will try to ask more challenging questions in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this function will change the original values in the matrix.

Call by value means the arguments to a function are copied onto the stack. The function can then modify these copies without changing the values outside. But this is never the case with arrays.

When you have an array as a parameter, it will always be converted to a pointer. This means

```
void powerup(char mat[9][9])
```

and

```
void powerup(char (*mat)[9])
```

are the same.

Comment: Thanks for the Help.